# Using NPAPI to detect browser minimize

Tags: plugins, npapi

Is there a way to use NPAPI to determine whether the browser is minimized.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly.  Depending on which platform you want (you should really specify things like that) there might be a way.

For example, on windows you might be able to get the browser HWND (NPN_GetValue with NPNVnetscapeWindow) and then check the state of that window with windows API calls.

On mac you're going to have a harder time of it; you could possibly intuit from the clipping information passed into NPP_SetWindow, but that doesn't tell you if the browser is minimized or if the plugin (or even the tab) is just not visible.  Again, you'd need to try to figure out a way to use system calls to find your way back to the real window, but on Mac that's going to be very non-trivial.

Linux I'm not sure; you get a GtkSocket if you use XEmbed (only thing Chromium supports) and I haven't a clue if you can use that to get back to where you'd need to be to check minimized state.

So the short answer is no; NPAPI doesn't provide anything like that. You'd just have to try to find something that it does provide that gives you enough info to hack it.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was using Core animation layer. I put in a timer which checks how often the candraw call back is called. If the time difference between the two callbacks are greater than a second I assume that either my plug-in is minimized or hidden.